# Converting tab delimited text file of unknown encoding to R-compatible file encoding in Python

Tags: r, python-2.7, encoding, file-conversion

I have many textfiles of unknown encoding which I wasn't able to open at all in R, where I would like to work with them. I ended up being able to open them in python with the help of `codecs` in UTF-16:

```
f = codecs.open(input,"rb","utf-16")
for line in f:
    print repr(line)
```

One line in my files now looks like this when printed in python:

```
u'06/28/2016\t14:00:00\t0,000\t\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
\x00\x00\x00\x00\t00000000\t6,000000\t0,000000\t144,600000\t12,050000
\t8,660000\t-120,100000\t-0,040000\t-0,110000\t1,340000\t5,360000
\t-1,140000\t-1,140000\t24,523000\t269,300000\t271,800000\t0,130000
\t272,000000\t177,000000\t0,765000\t0,539000\t\r\n'
```

The "u" in the beginning tells me that this in unicode, but now I don't really know what do with it. My goal is to convert the textfiles to something I can use in `R`, e.g. properly encoded csv, but I have failed using `unicodecsv`:

```
in_txt = unicodecsv.reader(f, delimiter = '\t', encoding = 'utf-8')
out_csv = unicodecsv.writer(open(output), 'wb', encoding = 'utf-8')

out_csv.writerows(in_txt)
```

Can anybody tell me what the principal mistake in my approach is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `guess_encoding(y)` from readr package in **R**. It is not 100% bullet proof but it has worked for me in the past and should at least get you pointed in the right direction:

```
guess_encoding(y)
#>     encoding confidence
#> 1 ISO-8859-2        0.4
#> 2 ISO-8859-1        0.3
```

try using `read_tsv()` to read-in your files and then try `guess_enconding()`

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks, `guess_encoding` helped a lot! just for completeness: it was a utf-16-le file full of null bytes (\x00) that I removed in python. after this and coversion to utf-8 everything worked fine in R!